# WinDbg - Every frame of CallStack window and Command show only ntdll! and KERNEL32! entries - no other modules even though all pdb's are loaded

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am using WinDbg.exe version 10.0.2 on a Windows Server 2019 and attached to a process sqlsrvr.exe trying to see the call stack used by that program. I mapped all .pdb symbol files correctly (at least command lm [shows that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Liz.png)) but the only entries shown in every Call Stack frame (and scrolling through Command window when Stepping with F11) are entries starting with "ntdll!" and "KERNEL32!". The problem is not just with sqlsrvr.exe but with any process I pick, for example after attaching to notepad.exe CallStack looks the same.
[image]

Comment: Are you able to switch to all other threads of that process to take a look? Not all threads showing interesting call stacks. If you are still learning WinDbg via a book or tutorial, move further and you will discover more.

Comment: Don't use that window. You want to use `k` along with `.logopen` so that you can review your actions in the logfile at a later time.

Comment: Other than that, it looks like you are on the debugger injected thread (`DbgUiRemoteBreakin()`), which isn't typically an interesting thread. Try switching to thread 0 (`~0s`).

Comment: Try running ~*k to view call stacks of all thread  you are viewing the debug break thread call stack